# Stranded connector cables with raspberry pi

Tags: hardware, connectors

Is it safe to use stranded connector cables with raspberry pi?

I suspect I blew my last RPi because I used the stranded connectors, don't want to get into the same situation again.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be safe?  I can't see the distinction you are drawing between stranded and single core cables.

Comment: @joan: The only distinction I can think of is the way they conduct electricity. I agree, conceptually they do the same thing and I would not have though about this had my last raspberry pi not misbehaved right after I started using stranded cables.  But, not that I have some confirmation, I would be more at ease knowing that I can use stranded cables without any repercussions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to stranded vs solid core cables there is no difference in this regard. I assume you are connecting these wires to GPIO pins of the pi?

The reason stranded wires exist is because they bend easily without breaking. They actually carry less current than solid core.  But carrying more current DOES NOT MEAN more voltage.  Whatever voltage you put on one end of the wire will appear at the other end. (For lengths under 100 feet or so).

If you post what you are trying to wire up maybe we can help you spot some potential problems with what you are making